# Is there a character formula over Cartan triples?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact semisimple Lie group, with $\mathfrak{g}$ its (real) Lie algebra. We also fix a choice of maximal torus $T$ in $G$, with corresponding Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}$, itself a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Let $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathfrak{t} \otimes \mathbb{R}^3 \simeq \mathfrak{t} \oplus \mathfrak{t} \oplus \mathfrak{t}$. We identify the $\mathbb{R}^3$ factor with the imaginary quaternions.

Given a complex representation $\pi$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, we define the character $\operatorname{ch}_\pi(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ to be the quaternionic trace of the exponential of $\pi(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ (here, by $\pi$ we really mean the quaternionification of $\pi$). Thus the values of the character map are quaternions.

(I think this definition of the character makes more sense than my previous convoluted definition in earlier versions of this post, but I still have to see if it completely makes sense.)

Is there a known character formula in this setting, which is analogous to Weyl's character formula?

Motivation: Cartan triples do occur in some important articles in the literature and may even be related to the Geometric Langlands program (see for instance the article by Witten and Gukov entitled "Gauge theory, ramification and the geometric Langlands program"). My interest comes from an article by Sir Michael Atiyah and Roger Bielawski (which may have inspired or influenced the above-mentioned article) entitled "Nahm's equations, configuration spaces and flag manifolds".